# How to close an AceGUI 3.0 Frame when escape is pressed?

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I'm using WowAce's Ace3 AceGUI library for a World of Warcraft AddOn. I'd like my Frame to be closed when escape is pressed, as is conventional in the game.

This is how the Frame is created:

```lua
    local frame = AceGUI:Create("Frame")
    frame:SetTitle("Flare")
    frame:SetStatusText("Ready")
    frame:SetCallback("OnClose", function(widget) AceGUI:Release(widget) end)
    frame:SetLayout("List")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a part of the World of Warcraft API, the `UISpecialFrames` table is provided as a global variable, and any string in that table will be fetched as key from the global variables table when the escape key is pressed; If that global variable is an open WoW Frame, it will be closed.

This means you'll have to declare your WoW Frame as a global variable and add the variable's name to the `UISpecialFrames` table with `table.insert`. Note that the WoW Frame of an AceGUI Frame is stored under its `frame` key. Put together in code:

```lua
    local frame = AceGUI:Create("Frame")
    frame:SetTitle("Flare")
    frame:SetStatusText("Ready")
    frame:SetCallback("OnClose", function(widget) AceGUI:Release(widget) end)
    frame:SetLayout("List")

    -- Add the frame as a global variable under the name `MyGlobalFrameName`
    _G["MyGlobalFrameName"] = frame.frame
    -- Register the global variable `MyGlobalFrameName` as a "special frame"
    -- so that it is closed when the escape key is pressed.
    tinsert(UISpecialFrames, "MyGlobalFrameName")
```